# Index wise Setstate onpress funtion for Radioform in react native

Tags: android, react-native, radio-button, react-native-flatlist

Hello I m  in new in react native. I need a solution that I have radioform inside flatlist. So there will be same number of radioform as flatlist row renders. I want to set state for react native onpress funtion. As I'm able to get the value of state of radioform but I want to get index wise . So how to set State index wise for Radioform . Here is my Radioform code inside flatlist.

```
 <RadioForm
            animation={true}
            buttonColor={"#C2E3A9"}
            index={index}
            formHorizontal={true}
            labelHorizontal={true}
            buttonStyle={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            radioStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
            //  labelHorizontal={false}
            style={styles.radiostyle}
            radio_props={radio_props}
            initial={this.state.typeofattendance[1]}
            isSelected = {true}

            **onPress={value => {this.setState({ typeofattendance: value});

              }**
            }
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the index in renderItem of FlatList

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {       
    return(   
        <View>
           <RadioForm
            animation={true}
            buttonColor={"#C2E3A9"}
            index={index}
            formHorizontal={true}
            labelHorizontal={true}
            buttonStyle={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            radioStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
            //  labelHorizontal={false}
            style={styles.radiostyle}
            radio_props={radio_props}
            initial={this.state.typeofattendance[1]}
            isSelected = {true}

            **onPress={value => {this.setState({ typeofattendance: value, index: index
});

              }**
            }
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          />
        </View>
      );
  }
```